# what should be the query for this? 2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i want to select record from

```
ID     DATE

1    2013-07-01
2    2013-07-02 
3    2013-07-03
4    2013-07-05
5    2013-07-06
6    2013-07-08
7    2013-07-10
8    2013-07-11
9    2013-07-12
```

result like:

```
DATE

2013-07-01 to 2013-07-03
2013-07-05 to 2013-07-06
2013-07-08
2013-07-10 to 2013-07-12
```

So if date is continuous like 1-2-3 then select 1-3.

What is sql query for this ?

Comment: Is there any kind of logic here? Coz I am not able to understand the logic.

Comment: What exactly is the pattern here? 1-3, 5-6, 8, 10-12 ?

Comment: Can you explain in detail about what u need,bcoz your code makes no sense..

Comment: It looks like the questions is about discrete and continuous intervals.

Comment: if date is like 1-2-3 then select 1-3.if date is 1-2-3-5-6 then select 1-3 and 5-6

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? This site is about getting help with concrete places you're stuck at, not about doing the work for you.

Comment: i am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to normalize a date series?

This is what i used when the datecol is unique:

```
SELECT
  MIN(datecol) AS StartVal,
  MAX(datecol) AS EndVal,
  COUNT(*) AS #IDs
FROM
 (
  SELECT
    datecol - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datecol ASC) AS grp,
    datecol
  FROM tab
 ) dt
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY 1
```

If your DBMS doesn't support Window Functions it's much more complicated.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59874/1) provided by [jyparask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2401981/jyparask)

Comment: Just some fixes in spelling (such as ROW_NUMBER instead of RW_NUMBER) and column naming... You may check this fiddle for a proper result based on this solution. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59874/1

Comment: it give me following result 2013-01-07 00:00:00.000 2013-01-07 00:00:00.000 1
2013-02-07 00:00:00.000 2013-02-07 00:00:00.000 1
2013-03-07 00:00:00.000 2013-03-07 00:00:00.000 1
2013-05-07 00:00:00.000 2013-05-07 00:00:00.000 1
2013-06-07 00:00:00.000 2013-06-07 00:00:00.000 1
2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 1
2013-10-07 00:00:00.000 2013-10-07 00:00:00.000 1
2013-11-07 00:00:00.000 2013-11-07 00:00:00.000 1
2013-12-07 00:00:00.000 2013-12-07 00:00:00.000 1

Comment: @jyparask: thanks for spotting the typos, fixed, and for the fiddle   Balwant Chaudhary: Should return the correct result, see fiddle

Comment: @dnoeth By all means if you like include the fiddle in your solution.